# почему в css не работает position:fixed

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, sass

Почему при адаптации меню проскроливается ?

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #212121;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 13px 70px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu_link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.menu_item {
  border-right: 2px dotted black;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.menu_item:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.subheader {
  height: 84px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.subheader_logo {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.subheader_official {
  margin-top: 6px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.subheader_phone {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.subheader_call {
  margin-top: 19px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.subheader_btn {
  margin-top: 19px;
  width: 172px;
  height: 46px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#1eacc7), to(#4ce2ff));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.subheader_btn:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #1eacc7;
}

.promo {
  min-height: 800px;
  background: url(../image/bg/first_bg.png) center center/cover;
  padding: 150px 0 135px 0;
}

.promo_header {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo_subheader {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo_descr {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 23px;
}

.promo_btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 118px auto 0 auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 259px;
  height: 63px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#1eacc7), to(#4ce2ff));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7 0%, #4ce2ff 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.promo_btn:hover {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #1eacc7;
}

.reason {
  min-height: 900;
  padding: 71px 0 65px 0;
}

.reason_item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 35px auto;
  max-width: 480px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.reason_round {
  width: 113px;
  height: 113px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #1eacc7;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.reason_text {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 21px;
  max-width: 341px;
}

.reason_subheader {
  color: #1eacc7;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.title {
  color: #222222;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 36px;
}

.title_white {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.label {
  margin-top: 36px;
  width: 112px;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000000;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.label_white {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #070716;
}

.subtitle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #222222;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 19px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subtitle_white {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.mobile {
  min-height: 864px;
  padding: 48px 0 79px 0;
  background: url("../image/bg/mobile_bg.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.mobile_item {
  width: 320px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  padding-top: 92px;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile_item_1 {
  background: url("../image/phone/1.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.mobile_item_2 {
  background: url("../image/phone/2.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.mobile_item_3 {
  background: url("../image/phone/3.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.mobile_item_4 {
  background: url("../image/phone/4.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.mobile_item_5 {
  background: url("../image/phone/5.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.mobile_item_6 {
  background: url("../image/phone/6.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.mobile_item_subtitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile_item_plus {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile_item_plus:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #1eacc7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.mobile_item_plus:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  height: 14px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #1eacc7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.mobile_item_plus:hover:before,
.mobile_item_plus:hover:after {
  background-color: #ff5656;
}

.mobile .row {
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.choice {
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #070716;
  padding-top: 37px;
}

.uber_car {
  background: url("../image/bg/mobile_bg.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
  min-height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.uber_car img {
  display: block;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: -270px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.uber_car .car_subtitle {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.require {
  padding: 68px 0 84px 0;
}

.require_block {
  margin: 33px 0;
}

.require_block_nmb {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.require_title {
  color: #1ca8c3;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.require_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.require_list li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.require_list li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -32px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 21px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("../icons/chekmark_blue.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.require_descr {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #1ca8c3;
}

.require .warning .require_title {
  color: #ff5656;
}

.require .warning .require_list li:before {
  background: url("../icons/chekmark_red.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.world {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 717px;
  padding: 49px 0;
  background: url("../image/bg/map.png") center center/cover no-repeat;
}

.world_link {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 49px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 68px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1fbad6;
}

.world_link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

footer {
  padding: 14px 23px 39px 23px;
}

footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer_divider {
  width: 299px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #1fbad6;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer_wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer_wrapper>div {
  width: 33%;
}

.footer_wrapper>div:nth-child(3) {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.footer_social {
  width: 160px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer_social_item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 4px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #070716;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer_social_item i {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer_links {
  width: 390px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer_links_main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer_links_main a {
  color: #070716;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer_links_sub {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.footer_links_sub a {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer_links_lang {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #1fbad6;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 19px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer_mobile img {
  max-width: 125px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .menu_item {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .menu_link {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .promo_header {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .reason_text {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .mobile_item {
    width: 295px;
    height: 275px;
  }
  .mobile_item_subtitle {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .footer_mobile img {
    max-width: 65px;
  }
  .footer_links_main a {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  .footer_links_sub {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10%);
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }
  .footer_links_lang {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10%);
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .menu_item {
    padding-right: 12px;
  }
  .menu_link {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .subheader_logo img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .subheader_official {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .subheader_phone {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .subheader_btn {
    width: 159px;
    height: 42px;
  }
  .promo_header {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .promo_subheader {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .reason_item {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .reason_text {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .footer_mobile img {
    max-width: 65px;
  }
  .footer_links_main {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .footer_links_main a {
    font-size: 9px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-45%);
    transform: translateX(-45%);
  }
  .footer_links_sub {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-28%);
    transform: translateX(-28%);
  }
  .footer_links_lang {
    font-size: 9px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20%);
    transform: translateX(-20%);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  nav {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu {
    position: fixed !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0d950b6e58.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a></li>
          <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a></li>
          <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании</a></li>
          <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a></li>
          <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a></li>
          <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="subheader">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
            <a href="" class="subheader_logo"><img src="/src/image/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            <div class="subheader_official">Официальный партнер Uber в Москве</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1 col-xl-2 offset-xl-2">
            <div class="subheader_call">Звоните нам ежедневно</div>
            <a href="tel:84957970988" class="subheader_phone">8 495 797 09 88</a>
          </div>
          <button class="subheader_btn">заказать звонок</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="promo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 offset-md-0 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
          <h1 class="promo_header">КОМПАНИЯ UBER PARTNERS!</h1>
          <h2 class="promo_subheader">ПРИГЛАШАЕМ ВОДИТЕЛЕЙ! НА СВОЕМ АВТО!</h2>
          <div class="promo_descr">
            Компания UBER динамически развивающаяся. Компания на рынке занимает лидирующее место среди таксомоторных компаний, Компания абсолютно прозрачная вы можете контролировать все процессы у себя в личном кабинете. Бонуcная система.Помимо выполненной работы
            по заказам, компания начисляет бонусы за пиковое время.
            <br><br> Мы одни из партнеров и зарекомендовали себя как одна из лучших команд в городе Москве. Водители у нас зарабатывают от 80000- 120000 в месяц.
          </div>
          <button class="promo_btn">ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="reason">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="black_title">
          <div class="label">преимущества</div>
          <div class="title">8 причин начать работать с нами</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

          <div class="reason_item">
            <div class="reason_round">
              <img src="/src/icons/first_blue_icons/1w.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="reason_text">
              <span class="reason_subheader">Никаких наличных, оплата происходит
                                        автоматически</span>
              <br> Стоимость поездки оплачивается пассажиром с привязанной банковской карты, т.е. нет никаких рисков связанных с перевозкой наличности как для пассажира, так и для водителя, Вам не нужно искать мелкие деньги для размена.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="reason_item">
            <div class="reason_round">
              <img src="/src/icons/first_blue_icons/2.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="reason_text">
              <span class="reason_subheader">Высокий доход с гарантированными
                                        выплатами</span>
              <br> Мы выплачиваем заработную плату на личную банковскую карту водителя! Вам не нужно оформлять ООО, ИП, платить налоги, подавать декларацию, оплачивать бухгалтерские услуги и ведение банковского счета.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="reason_item">
            <div class="reason_round">
              <img src="/src/icons/first_blue_icons/3.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="reason_text">
              <span class="reason_subheader">Комфортное, прозрачное и простое
                                        подключение</span>
              <br> Мы подключаем дистанционно и бесплатно, Вам нет необходимости приезжать к нам! Вы присылаете нам копии документов, мы регистрируем Вас и присылаем данные для подключения, через 1-2 дня Вы можете начинать работать!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="reason_item">
            <div class="reason_round">
              <img src="/src/icons/first_blue_icons/4.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="reason_text">
              <span class="reason_subheader">Круглосуточная поддержка</span>
              <br> В Uber действует круглосуточная поддержка водителей по электронной почте. Если что-то непонятно, Вы всегда можете задать вопрос через On-line консультацию.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="reason_item">
            <div class="reason_round">
              <img src="/src/icons/first_blue_icons/5.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="reason_text">
              <span class="reason_subheader">Комиссия 8% + БОНУСЫ</span>
              <br> Комиссия 8% + БОНУСЫ У нас минимальная комиссия и мы выплачиваем бонусы за каждую поездку, некоторые наши конкуренты оставляют бонусы себе. Мы работаем честно и с нами водители зарабатывают больше!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="reason_item">
            <div class="reason_round">
              <img src="/src/icons/first_blue_icons/6.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="reason_text">
              <span class="reason_subheader">Работа в удобное время, никаких
                                        графиков</span>
              <br> Вы просто нажимаете кнопку выйти на линию для начала работы, когда решите закончить, нажимаете выйти с линии. Вы можете подрабатывать только утром, вечером, в выходные или праздничные дни!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="reason_item">
            <div class="reason_round">
              <img src="/src/icons/first_blue_icons/7.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="reason_text">
              <span class="reason_subheader">Всегда большое количество заказов</span>
              <br> Приложение показывает, где на данный момент больше всего заказов и где действуют повышенные тарифы. У Вас не будет простоя и холостых пробегов. Наши пассажиры всегда приятные и абсолютно неконфликтные люди, которых приятно возить.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="reason_item">
            <div class="reason_round">
              <img src="/src/icons/first_blue_icons/8.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="reason_text">
              <span class="reason_subheader">Без шашечек и наклеек</span>
              <br> Вам не нужно менять цвет, устанавливать «шашки» на автомобиль и обклеивать его наклейками.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="mobile">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label">Возможности</div>
      <div class="title">мобильное приложение убер</div>
      <div class="subtitle">Сделайте заказ, совершите поездку и оплатите ее стоимость, используя свой мобильный телефон</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="mobile_item mobile_item_1">
            <div class="mobile_item_subtitle">оформление заказа одним касанием</div>
            <div class="mobile_item_plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="mobile_item mobile_item_2">
            <div class="mobile_item_subtitle">надежная подача</div>
            <div class="mobile_item_plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="mobile_item mobile_item_3">
            <div class="mobile_item_subtitle">прозрачные цены</div>
            <div class="mobile_item_plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="mobile_item mobile_item_4">
            <div class="mobile_item_subtitle">безналичная оплата</div>
            <div class="mobile_item_plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="mobile_item mobile_item_5">
            <div class="mobile_item_subtitle">обратная связь</div>
            <div class="mobile_item_plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="mobile_item mobile_item_6">
            <div class="mobile_item_subtitle">разделить стоимость поездки</div>
            <div class="mobile_item_plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="choice">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="label label_white">возможности</div>
      <div class="title title_white">Выбор - отличная штука!</div>
      <div class="subtitle subtitle_white">Закажите автомобиль, который подходит вам по стилю и бюджету</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: как написали так и работает, у вас фиксированная позиция nav только относительно header,а не window, читайте внимательно про absolute а потом про fixed https://learn.javascript.ru/position#position-absolute

Comment: Всё же работает

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков С fixed вложенность не работает вроде, оно всегда независимо от вложенности будет размещаться относительно window. Логика, которую Вы объясняете, применима к absolute в relative.